# How to debug Deno applications in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, deno

Just like Node.js.

Running and debugging Node.js [NodeJs Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#)

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41607#focus=streamItem-27-4146419.0-0 for some tips on working with Deno in Webstorm

Comment: Okay!, Thanks @lena...

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm supports the **V8 Inspector Protocol**, so you're good:

1. Go to "Debug Configurations" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>)
2. Add a configuration ("+" on top left corner)
3. Select "Attach to Node.js/Chrome"
4. Make sure the "Chrome" option is selected (should be default)

[image]

5. Click "Apply" and "Debug" to start the debugger
6. Create your breakpoints
7. With the debugger running, run your script with the `--inspect-brk` option:

```sh
deno run --inspect-brk -A app.ts
```

Now it will work as intended with the IDE. You can use the Debug view to step in, over, etc.

[image]

We should expect a plugin some time in the future.

From [deno debugger](https://deno.land/manual/tools/debugger):

> Deno supports the V8 Inspector Protocol.
>
> It's possible to debug Deno programs using Chrome Devtools or other clients that support the protocol (eg. VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

You can run and debug files using Deno with the [Deno plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14382-deno).